# When the server runs using jar file it gives curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: java, maven, http, curl

I have created http backend server(Has an async behavior) using java. When I just execute the main method using ide and execute the `curl http://localhost:2385/v2/pet/3` it gives the response as expected in curl.

Following Is my main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    backEndServerPort = 238o;
    MockBackEndServer mockBackEndServer = new MockBackEndServer(backEndServerPort);
    mockBackEndServer.start();

}
```

this is some code part of the server.

```
 httpServer.createContext(contextV3 + "/pet/", exchange -> {

            InputStream is =  exchange.getRequestBody();
            byte [] response = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            exchange.getResponseHeaders().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(),
                    CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, response.length);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write(response);
            exchange.close();
        });
```

But when I created the jar file from the project and execute the jar file using the following command(added the maven-jar-plugin to run the main method), it doesen't give the response as expected.
This is the jar execution command.

`java -jar MockBackendServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

when I run the same `curl http://localhost:2385/v2/pet/3` it gives the following

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

and from the postman, I get this error

```
Error: socket hang up
```

also when I create the server as synchronize mode and run the jar file in debug mode using  `java -jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005 MockBackendServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` it also gives the results as expected.

As I suspect this happens because of some delay. So anyone has any solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. When I was setting the content type as

`exchange.getResponseHeaders().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE.toString(),CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);`

the "content-type" i have get like this.

```
HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE.toString()
```

That leads to the error.

So I statically define it as "content-type" and it worked.

In the previous implementation when it executes the `HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE.toString()`   line may produce an error or some delay when running it from the jar file.

Comment: So what ended up being the solution?